# Select search result and return ID value

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have this following statement. "ls_query" is returning the address field.  Is there a way of getting the id of this address field from the database?

Following code is getting the search result (Which is address) from mysql database and replacing the demo value.

```
    function myFunction() {

        var x = document.getElementById("ls_query");
        var adr = x.value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "address is:" +adr;

        }
    </script>
```

I am not sure how but I need to GET the 'id' of this selected 'address' from the database. Program should select the specific address from the search box and post the ID value. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can send `AJAX` request to `PHP` script on Your server that will return ID

Add to JS some function like this:

```
function getIdByAddress(address) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', 'handler.php?address=' + address, false);

    xhr.send();

    if (xhr.status != 200) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return xhr.responseText;
    }

}
```

Then call it in Your function:

```
function myFunction() {

    var x = document.getElementById("ls_query");
    var adr = x.value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "address is:" +adr;

    var id = getIdByAddress(adr);

}
```

And create in PHP something like this:

```
<?php

    // here You establish connection to database

    if(!empty($_GET['address'])) {

        // escape $_GET['address']
        // make query to database and fetch data

        // print fetched data to screen

    }

?>
```

If there are already prepared addresses in Your HTML then You can just add `data-id` attribute to each address block and then fetch it in Your JS function:

```
function myFunction() {

    var x = document.getElementById("ls_query");
    var adr = x.value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "address is:" +adr;

    var id = x.id;

}
```